# Use static keyword in a for loop?

Tags: php

I want to use the `static` keyword in my for loop.

Is it possible? if yes then how?

**Here is my code:**

```
$current_time = date('h:i A');
    <select>

        for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            if ($i=0) {
              echo "<option>" . date("h:i A", $current_time) . "</option>";
            }else{
              static $tNow = strtotime("+15 minutes",strtotime($current_time));
              echo "<option>" . date("h:i A", $tNow) . "</option>";
            }
        }
     <select>
```

When I'm using the `static` keyword, I'm getting a php error.

I want to display a `<select>` element with each option being 15 minutes steps, like `12:00`, `12:15`, `12:30`.

Comment: **what** exactly are you trying to **achieve** by this?

Comment: But why do You need to use it ?

Comment: what is your goal by using a **static** keyword ? have you read when/in which cases we can use this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php ?

Comment: yes.. when a function is completed/executed, all of its variables are deleted. However, sometimes we want a local variable NOT to be deleted. We need it for a further job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you want to use `static keyword` in your code, but as suggested you should read here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php, how and when to use `static keyword`.
If your goal is to display dropdown and getting option value different 15mint time
like this 12:00, 12:15, 12:30..... this is my solution:

```
$current_time[0] = date('h:i A');
echo"<select>";
echo "<option>" . $current_time[0] . "</option>";
$step=0;
for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) {
    $step=$step+15;
    $current_time[$i] = strtotime("+".$step." minutes", strtotime($current_time[0]));
    echo "<option>" . date("h:i A", $current_time[$i]) . "</option>";
}

echo"</select>";
var_dump($current_time);
```

Working code here: http://ideone.com/zM0eue

Explanation: I used an array to contain all `strtotime` output in `for loop`. Each time I used the same `$current_time[0]` to calculate new `$current_time[$i]` with a `$step` variable incremented by +15 each time.